# Cannot log into Workgroup Manager

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, osx-server

I recently reinstalled the Mac Mini Server using Snow Leopard-server, but using the account I created during setup (allegedly the server administrator account) I cannot authenticate to the LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 store.

Using the diradmin account I can get limited (cannot change anything) access (after waiting a long time) using the same password as the 'standard' admin account. Also, using the `root` account I can log in fine.

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: You local administrator (the account you created at setup) shouldn't have rights over the LDAP domain, so that part's normal.  But you should be able to use diradmin.  The delay sounds to me like a DNS issue -- try un `host $HOSTNAME` to see if your server's name is mapped to its IP address in DNS.  Also, run `sudo changeip -checkhostname` to check the reverse mapping (but if it reports a mismatch, you probably shouldn't trust its advice about fixing it).

Comment: FYI, you must be working on the server not remotely. This may be relevant.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That comment would make a good answer. Shift it and I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Aparently it *does* work if I use the 'root' account, don't know if that's even The Right Way™, but it suffices for now.